# a tricky graph solve in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

As the following, I built a graph with two big variables and two input placeholder. 
Every time, I want to use the current value of variables (partial values) and input placeholders to calculate delta values. Then the delta values are update  to the variables using scatter_add.

problem: the two computing paths are not the same, one needs more computing. the tensorflow solving engine seems to prefer one of the path randomly-it solves one of path, then the other. For example, tf may update variable 0 first, then use this new variable 0 to solve another path (update variable 1). This is not my need.

so, any idea?

tensorflow graph:

[image: tensorflow graph]

Comment: How do you want it to be?! There are dependencies here... TF has to exec one of the two options..

Comment: Thank you for your response. I want TF solves the update delta  based on current variables first, then the delta values are updated to the variables. "TF has to exec one of the two options" means one of the two paths?

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution. Using the tf.control_dependencies() could solve this problem.
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/control_dependencies